# How to add font Calibri for FPDF in php?

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf

I have trying to add a Calibri font. I have tried the following:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Calibri','',9);
```

However, when I try to run it, I got this error:

Message: FPDF error: Undefined font: calibri

I have trying to add a Calibri font. I have tried the following:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Calibri','',9);
```

Comment: Do other fonts work fine? Or is it just Calibri? Confirm Calibri has been installed and exists locally based on FPDF documentation.

Comment: You should follow [this tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm).

Comment: You should follow this http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm  and generate font http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/